# Ionic Camera Plugin and input[type=file]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova

> Is there a method in `angularjs` where I can use the Photos after they
>   are taken with the `CordovaCamera` Plugin and then convert those
>   images into files?

I have used the `File()` class but then found out that the `FileConstructor` is not supported by safari, I also searched for replacements for this class but did not find any.

Comment: Could you please look into [this thread](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-make-uploading-files-or-images-using-ionicframwork-or-angularjs/391/9).. I hope it would help

Comment: This actually did the trick! Can you maybe explain to me just some of the mechanics. Like what format the images are being uploaded as are they files? and also how would this example handle arrays? @PankajParkar